# Python non-numpy matrixes issue

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have the following issue:

I have a list of lists with the following declaration:

```
As = [[0]*3]*3
```

I then try to change the values of this "matrix" with this:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        As[i][j] = calculate(A, i, j)*((-1)**(i+j))
```

As you may have guessed, this is used in calculating the inverse of a 3x3 matrix.

The function calculate returns the following values:

```
4.0     
-2.0    
-3.0    
-4.0    
-10.0   
9.0     
4.0     
10.0    
-21.0
```

However, As has the following value:

`[[4.0, -10.0, -21.0], [4.0, -10.0, -21.0], [4.0, -10.0, -21.0]]`, which is unexpected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your first line:

```
As = [[0]*3]*3
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
a = [0] * 3
As = [a] * 3
```

`As` therefore contains three references to the same list:

```
>>> for a in As:
...     print(id(a))
...
4293437996
4293437996
4293437996
```

So when you change this list, it's reflected in all of the rows of your matrix.

To get around this, you can use a list comprehension to construct the outer list:

```
As = [[0] * 3 for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Note that the inner list `[0] * 3` is fine, since the list contains only an integer, which is immutable.  It therefore doesn't matter that the list refers to the *same instance* of that integer, since they can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

When you build a list like this `[[0]*3]*3` you are creating 3 references to the same list, use a list comprehension instead:

```
[[0 for _ in xrange(3)] for _ in xrange(3)]
```

See how in the comprehension here just the `[0][0]` is modified:

```
>>> l1 = [[0]*3]*3
>>> l1[0][0] = 10
>>> l1
[[10, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0]]
>>> l2 = [[0 for _ in xrange(3)] for _ in xrange(3)]
>>> l2[0][0] = 10
>>> l2
[[10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: There's no need to construct the inner list using a comprehension.  In fact, the list will refer to the same `int` instances anyway, since Python caches integers in `[-5, 256]`.  The result is therefore identical to `[0] * 3`.

Comment: @WillVousden, it was just for clarifiying the concept, It usually clears my mind to use for ranges instead of `*` operator for this purpouse